# Visual studio crashes as soon as I open aspx or ascx View from MVC 2.0 project

Tags: visual-studio-2008, asp.net-mvc-2

Visual studio crashes as soon as I open aspx or ascx View from MVC 2.0 project.
If I delete all bin and obj folders from projects, I can open aspx and ascx View page. But it crashes again after compiling.

It started to crash after I moved strong typed model to different project.

I got stuck and cannot go further, really frustrated!

I'm using Visual staudio 2008 Sp1. MVC 2.0, Window xp sp3. .NET 3.5 sp1.

Anyone can help?

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I did to fix, something that I think is the same problem but I was seeing in a different way.

When I clicked on the Go To View command from the controller, VS tried to open the View and it crashed.

In order to fix this I did the following:

- Clean your solution
- Delete your bin folder.  (for some reason I had bin as part of the project, make sure you exclude it from the project if that is the case)
- Remove the MVC references from the project, i.e. (System.Web.Mvc, System.Web.Abstractions, and System.Web.Routing), Save, and re-add them again.
- Make sure all your references are resolved.
- Compile the whole solution.

Note, I used this resource for the solution:   http://darrell.mozingo.net/2009/01/28/aspnet-mvc-rc-1-visual-studio-crash/

I hope this helps.

Andres.